# Revit API. Get a room from the linked model in which the main model element is located

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a quite simple but at the same time challenging problem with Revit Api.
There is a Main Revit-MEP model and Linked architectural one. I want to know which room my MEP-elements belong. For this purpose, I have tried two ways:

1. Use `ElementIntersectsFilter` for link model (There is an article on Jeremy blog) – it doesn’t work when link rotated or displaced.
2. Import Solid geometry and transform solid, then use `ElementIntersectsSolidFilter` – it works, but take an enormous amount of time. For example, my Main model has at about 35000 elements and Linked 1100 rooms. The 95% of time spent for pass throw `ElementIntersectsSolidFilter`. For one room 30 sec avg which means hang on a system on 9 hours!

Filter all target elements from MainModel  (~35000 elems)

```
ICollection<ElementId> fec = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
.WhereElementIsNotElementType()
.WherePasses(new ElementMulticategoryFilter(bic))
.ToElementIds()
.ToList();
```

Get all Rooms from link and retrieve solids (~1100 elems)

```
IEnumerable<Room> rooms = new FilteredElementCollector(link.GetLinkDocument())
.WhereElementIsNotElementType()
.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Rooms)
.Cast<Room>();
```

RoomInfo holds solid and other additional information about Room

rlf – do all retrieving work

```
IEnumerable<RoomInfo> ifs = rlf.GetItemInfos(rooms).Cast<RoomInfo>();
```

A method that takes solid and the reference to collection of target elements.
Return all elements intersect solid and remove them from target collection (~35000) so the collection is rising down with every iteration.

```
        Public ICollection<ElementId> GetIntersectedElements(Solid solid, ref ICollection<ElementId> eIds)
        {
            if (!eIds.Any())
            {
                log.Info($"Input collection is empty. Task done.");
                return new List<ElementId>();
            }
            var solidFilter = new ElementIntersectsSolidFilter(solid);

            var fec = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, eIds)
           // This filter eat time
                .WherePasses(solidFilter)
                .ToElementIds();

            if (fec.Any())
            {
                eIds = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, eIds)
                    .Excluding(fec)
                    .ToElementIds();
            }
            return fec;
        }
```

**I will be appreciated for any ideas how to do this in a reasonable amount of time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this more simply and effectively. You need to figure out the transformation between the model main MEP model and linked architectural one. Next determine the location P of your family instance or MEP element or whatever. Transform P from the MEP model to the linked architectural model. In the architectural model, figure out what room or space contains the transformed point.

A recent thread in the Revit API discussion forum handles a different topic and yet illustrates almost all the principles required: [How to calculate the column finish area of room](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-calculate-the-column-finish-area-of-room/m-p/9576200).